# How to get through each properties and test the value?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have an object and I need to go through each `theCtns.services.depends_on` and test each value of this property. If the value is equal to my target value I want to remove it.

```js
var theCtns = {
  "version": "2",
  "networks": {
    "default": {
      "ipam": {
        "config": [
          {
            "subnet": "0.0.0.0/26",
            "gateway": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "services": {
    "serviceOne": {
      "image": "img1",
      "container_name": "serviceOneName",
      "volumes": [
        "x:x"
      ],
      "environment": [
        "SOMETHING=bla",
        "SOMETHINGELSE=bli"
      ],
      "depends_on": [
        "serviceTwo",
        "serviceX"
      ]
    },
    "serviceTwo": {
      "image": "img2",
      "container_name": "serviceTwoName",
      "volumes": [
        "x:x"
      ],
      "environment": [
        "SOMETHING=bla",
        "SOMETHINGELSE=bli"
      ],
      "depends_on": [
        "serviceX"
      ]
    }
  }
}


for (var i= theCtns.services.length-1; i>=0; i--){
 for (var j= theCtns.services[i].depends_on.length-1; j>=0; j--){
    if (theCtns.services[i].depends_on[j] === "serviceTwo") {
        theCtns.services[i].depends_on.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }
//theCtns.services[i].depends_on = theCtns.services[i].depends_on.filter(x=>x!=="serviceTwo")
}


console.log(theCtns)
```

*in reality this object can have more than 8 services but 2 are suffisent to solve my problem*

So my loop should go in `each service` then `each depends_on` and test the value but it looks like my loop is wrong somewhere

[EDIT] corrected the `lenght` typo

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Abhidev I already provide a snippet but if you prefer I can do a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ysjo9cm4/3/ but nothing appears with  `console.log`

Comment: @Rajesh it changes nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is `theCtns.services` is an object and you are trying to use an incremental loop to iterate it like an array. You need to iterate the keys of the object instead using a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

```js
var theCtns = {
  "version": "2",
  "networks": {
    "default": {
      "ipam": {
        "config": [
          {
            "subnet": "0.0.0.0/26",
            "gateway": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "services": {
    "serviceOne": {
      "image": "img1",
      "container_name": "serviceOneName",
      "volumes": [
        "x:x"
      ],
      "environment": [
        "SOMETHING=bla",
        "SOMETHINGELSE=bli"
      ],
      "depends_on": [
        "serviceTwo",
        "serviceX"
      ]
    },
    "serviceTwo": {
      "image": "img2",
      "container_name": "serviceTwoName",
      "volumes": [
        "x:x"
      ],
      "environment": [
        "SOMETHING=bla",
        "SOMETHINGELSE=bli"
      ],
      "depends_on": [
        "serviceX"
      ]
    }
  }
}


for (var i in theCtns.services){
  if(theCtns.services.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      for (var j= theCtns.services[i].depends_on.length-1; j>=0; j--){
        if (theCtns.services[i].depends_on[j] === "serviceTwo") {
            theCtns.services[i].depends_on.splice(j, 1);
        }
      }
  }
}


console.log(theCtns)
```

Comment: Wow impressive, ok I see my error. Thank you for the nice input

Answer (score 1):

`theCtns.services` is not an `Array` and you are trying to iterate through it as if it was one. It is actually an `Object`.
An `Object` has no length, that is why your loop was going wrong. Also `theCtns.services[i]` was wrong because it was referring to values such as `theCtns.services[0]` that do not exist.
I changed your code so that `i` takes its values from the actual keys of your object.

```js
var theCtns = {
  "version": "2",
  "networks": {
    "default": {
      "ipam": {
        "config": [
          {
            "subnet": "0.0.0.0/26",
            "gateway": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "services": {
    "serviceOne": {
      "image": "img1",
      "container_name": "serviceOneName",
      "volumes": [
        "x:x"
      ],
      "environment": [
        "SOMETHING=bla",
        "SOMETHINGELSE=bli"
      ],
      "depends_on": [
        "serviceTwo",
        "serviceX"
      ]
    },
    "serviceTwo": {
      "image": "img2",
      "container_name": "serviceTwoName",
      "volumes": [
        "x:x"
      ],
      "environment": [
        "SOMETHING=bla",
        "SOMETHINGELSE=bli"
      ],
      "depends_on": [
        "serviceX"
      ]
    }
  }
}


for (var i in theCtns.services){
  console.log(i);
  for (var j= theCtns.services[i].depends_on.length-1; j>=0; j--){
    if (theCtns.services[i].depends_on[j] === "serviceTwo") {
        theCtns.services[i].depends_on.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }
}


console.log(theCtns)
```

Comment: It the same as @MrCode but thank you too for the input and to show me my error

Answer (score 1):

Check the modified code, since it's not an array but an object, you need to use for...var. Also, you can directly make use of array methods to find the target value in the depends_on field.

```
var theCtns = {
      "version": "2",
      "networks": {
        "default": {
          "ipam": {
            "config": [
              {
                "subnet": "0.0.0.0/26",
                "gateway": "0.0.0.0"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "services": {
        "serviceOne": {
          "image": "img1",
          "container_name": "serviceOneName",
          "volumes": [
            "x:x"
          ],
          "environment": [
            "SOMETHING=bla",
            "SOMETHINGELSE=bli"
          ],
          "depends_on": [
            "serviceTwo",
            "serviceX"
          ]
        },
        "serviceTwo": {
          "image": "img2",
          "container_name": "serviceTwoName",
          "volumes": [
            "x:x"
          ],
          "environment": [
            "SOMETHING=bla",
            "SOMETHINGELSE=bli"
          ],
          "depends_on": [
            "serviceX"
          ]
        }
      }
    }

    for (var idx in theCtns.services) {
        var deps_idx = 
        theCtns.services[idx].depends_on.indexOf('serviceTwo');
        if (deps_idx) {
            theCtns.services[idx].depends_on.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(theCtns.services);
```

Comment: I used the solution of @MrCode  but thank you for taking the time to resolve my problem